# how to register plugin manually in capacitor 3?

Tags: java, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I am trying to use a plugin for background location tracking on Android. Capacitor is supposed to register the plugin automatically in MainActivity.java, but that's not happening. I tried to do that manually, but that is also not happening.

```java
package com.siloc.users;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.hemangkumar.capacitorgooglemaps.CapacitorGoogleMaps;
import com.equimaps.capacitor_background_geolocation.BackgroundGeolocation;
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        registerPlugin(CapacitorGoogleMaps.class);
        registerPlugin(BackgroundGeolocation.class);
     
    }

}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
`registerPlugins(Collections.singletonList(CapacitorGoogleMaps.class));`

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add details about it ?